# Impedir indexamento de recortes da pagina

Tags: php, html, seo, robots.txt

Se recortar uma pagina separando o `head`,`nav`, etc... E puxar tudo com `include` no `index.php`, o Google vai indexar essas paginas recortadas?

Quero separar algumas partes criando `head.php` e `nav.php`, depois vou puxar para dentro do index fazendo um `include`, mas preciso que o google faça a indexação da minha index MAS não faça a indexação dos arquivos `head.php` e `nav.php` pois esses serão apenas recortes para facilitar na manutenção, isso é possivel?

Visto que se eu der um no index no arquivo `head.php` os robos de buscas não só vão parar de indexar o `head.php` mas também vão parar de indexar minha index inteira pois estarei puxando o arquivo nela, como proceder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O google "vê" e processa apenas o que o teu servidor manda como resposta, de maneira simples se clicares com o botão direito do rato e clicares em ver fonte (*view page source* para browsers em inglês) é isso que o google processa, apesar de conseguir ir um pouco mais longe e identificar/processar manipulações do DOM com javascript com recurso por exemplo a ferramentas como [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

De qualquer maneira o google e outros motores de busca não conseguem identificar os processos internos do servidor, apenas o que este manda para o lado cliente e os processos que ocorrem neste lado (no browser).

Ex:

head.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SO PT</title>
    </head>
```

index.php

```
<?php include('head.php'); ?>
<body>
    <h1>Olá SO PT</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Os web crawlews da google daqui (index.php) vão processar/ver apenas:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SO PT</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Olá SO PT</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Não vai saber se o head.php foi "injetado" no `index.php` via um `include/require`.

Desta maneira e para responder diretamente à tua pergunta, desta maneira não tens como incumbir os robots de ver somente uma parte da página.

Comment: mas o google faz uma busca no servidor por arquivos, nesse caso ele consegue fazer a captura de todos arquivos publicos no servidor, ate mesmo um scanner como Vega consegue fazer a captura desses arquivos, ou estou errado? tanto que ate arquivos de texto da qual o site não faz nenhum chamada o google e alguns scanners conseguem encontrar de boa, é por isso que acredito que eles também irão encontrar os arquivos recortados como o head.php e nav.php por exemplo

Comment: @OtavioFagundes, esses softwares vão indo por tentativas e vendo se o servidor responde de alguma maneira de forma a verem se estes existem. Por exemplo, http://migueldvl.com/nao_ver_conteudos , aqui é preciso ir por tentativas e ir experimentanto se algum url responde alguma coisa, se experimentassem http://migueldvl.com/nao_ver_conteudos/ola.php , já encontrariam esse ficheiro, MAS nunca (partindo do príncipio que está tudo bem em termos de segurança) conseguirá ver o conteudo do ficheiro entre as tags `<?php ... ?>;`.

Comment: Isso seria um erro tremendo, porque teria acesso a informação sensível. Por ex: configuração da base de dados, do pŕoprio servidor etc... De qualquer maneira não acho e tenho 99% de certeza que o google não se baseia nisto para indexação do teu site, mesmo que de alguma maneira consiga ver que tens o head.php separado do index.php, isso não deve influenciar em nada